Get Windows startup folder from CMD with different system language
I'm trying to get Windows (10/11) startup folder location in a system whose language is French.
Normally, I use this command to get the folder location:
set "startupFolder=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
echo %startupFolder%

But when system language is French, the folder path is like below:
"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Menu Démarrer\Programmes\Démarrage"

How can I make sure my command will return startup folder location in all languages, not just English or French?

Please read my answer on path of user desktop in batch files or the answer linked in this answer. Next run in a command prompt window reg QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Startup. If you take my code, replace all occurrences of Desktop by Startup and use instead of if not defined DesktopFolder set "DesktopFolder=%UserProfile%\Desktop" the line if not defined StartupFolder set "StartupFolder=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup", you have a perfect working code.

The Startup folder is always stored in Windows registry. It is very unlikely that the last condition is ever true resulting in the definition of the environment variable StartupFolder with the standard English path. That line is just for a worst case scenario on heavy corrupted registry keys User Shell Folders and Shell Folders with Startup missing under both keys which is not yet automatically repaired by Windows as done on next user sign/log in with adding default Startup at least under key Shell Folders.

You can get the location from the users registry branch HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders under the Startup value.
Example:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "UserBranch=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
Set "ShellFolder=Startup"

Set "%ShellFolder%="
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=1-2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%UserBranch%" /V "%ShellFolder%" 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G=%%I"
If Defined %ShellFolder% (Set %ShellFolder%) & Pause

The above code however will not be directly changeable for all Values under the User Key, for example History, (due to ignoring End Of Lines beginning with H), and Local AppData, My Music, My Pictures, My Video, and Start Menu, (due to the space in their value names). The same would be true for Common AppData, Common Desktop, Common Documents, Common Programs, Common Start Menu, Common Startup, and Common Templates under the Machine Key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders.
If you wish therefore to be able to use the code for those cases too, you could modify it to cater for all scenarios.
Example:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
Set "ShellFolder=Common Start Menu"

Set "Branch=\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
Set "%ShellFolder: =_%="
For /F "Tokens=1-2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%RootKey%%Branch%" /V "%ShellFolder%" 2^>NUL') Do (
    If "%%H" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" (Set "%%G=%%I") Else (Set "_=%%I"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F "Tokens=*" %%J In ("!_:*REG_EXPAND_SZ=!") Do EndLocal & Set "%ShellFolder: =_%=%%J"
    )
)
If Defined %ShellFolder: =_% (Set %ShellFolder: =_%) & Pause

